# How to display stereoscopic pictures on a web page?

Tags: html, activex, npapi, stereo-3d, stereoscopy

A simple question, but I couldn’t find the answer anywhere. It appears there’s no native browser support for that *(but I maybe wrong and maybe an image format supportting stereocopic data is supported by at least one web browser)*.

I’m not talking about things like anaglyph or side by side display, the aim is to output stereoscopic pictures on stereoscopic capable monitors *(which often involve wearing electric glasses)*.

So how to do this without having to run unrestricted code through ActiveX or npapi for quad bufferring ?

Comment: Have you tried this :
https://github.com/moul/3d-stereo-html5

Comment: try this https://github.com/oscarmarinmiro/aframe-stereo-component

Comment: @HimanshuChaudhary I said I don t want things like side by side or anaglyph, but to use the capacity of stereoscopic rendering. This is something possible by using opengl or direct3d quad buffering with a npapi or activeX plugin *(and there is a fork of vlc for nvidia 3d vision)*. But as npapi and ActiveX is being phased out, I will soon have to use a vulnerable and outdated web browser.

Comment: Well in my opinion 3d display is dying breed anyways so it will be hard to find in this direction or one can just hope for web-assembly to be supported soon by major browsers so that one can extend the thin client to handle such situation.

Comment: @HimanshuChaudhary it depends were you re living. Nvidia added the ability to use stereoscopic rendering with opengl and direct3d on their consumer card this year. No, web assembly won t solve this like native client do not. In order to perform this at the os level you need to run the plugin at the same level of any applications on the os in order to get full access of the host native s graphic api. Especially on Linux were writing to `/dev` on the host file system is required for OpenGl.

Comment: Though as the web start enhacing for low level access without needing running os level plugins, maybe a lower level solution than webgl exists, especially since web browser are removing support for native api rendering.